# setting a button two tasks but only doing one at a time depending on toggle state

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I'll just go through the scenario to try and help, I want to be able to push b1 and for it to change/setText to t1 unless t3 has changed due to b2. When this has occcured i'd like it setText for t2. I've made this app as simple as i can with many different methods of checking if t3 had been changed yet to no prevail. I've tried while statements and str.matches(t3).

Thank you, ideally Id like to be able to do this by checking the contents of t3 not with a toggle but i've provided the code with the toggle to show that it didn't work with that.

Thanks in advance :)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

Button b1, b2;
TextView t1, t2, t3;
String str, str1;
ToggleButton toggle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);


    str1 = t3.getText().toString();

     b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {

             t3.setText("Hello");
             toggle.setChecked(true);

         }
     });

    {
        if (toggle.isChecked() == true) {

            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    t2.setText("Success!");


                }
            });

        } else if (toggle.isChecked() == false) {
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    str = t1.getText().toString();
                    t1.setText(str + "1");

                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write something like this, simple and nice

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

Button b1, b2;
TextView t1, t2, t3;
String str, str1;
ToggleButton toggle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);



    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            t3.setText("Hello");
            toggle.setChecked(true);

        }
    });

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          //t2.setText( ((toggle.isChecked()) ? "Success!" : (t1.getText().toString() + "1") ) );

         if(toggle.isChecked()){
          t2.setText("Success!");
         }else{
          t1.setText(t1.getText().toString() + "1");

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, that nearly worked but you've stated that t2 will either equal success or (t1 + 1). I needed for the toggle to either make the b1 change t1 or t2. This answer only changes t2. Thank you anyway, you've shown me another method of attacl for the problem :)

Comment: i have edited the answer, i didn see tat you are changing two different text values. try giving a meaningful name instead of `b`, `t` `x` `y` and `z`. Thats one quality of a good programmer :)

Comment: Thanks alot :) that worked, that's a lot simpler method and more concise than anything I could come up with. Yeah I know, it started to confuse me too aha, this is just a test app for the principal of what I am trying to do so thought that Id name them simply but it made it more confusing sorry. Thanks again, you've thought me the new method with the boolean expression and ? :.